# Create a new function generically

Tags: javascript, function, generics

I dont know if the question is right, but I want to know is it possible to create functions generically?
Lets say instead of doing this:

```
function f1{
  $("#pictureID1").remove();
}
```

and

```
function f2{
  $("#pictureID2").remove();
}
```

JSON

```
var content = [
   {"functionname": "f1", "image": "pictureID1"},
   {"functionname": "f2", "image": "pictureID2"},
];
```

I want to create them automatically like this:

```
for(var i=1;i<=2;i++{
    new function content[i].functionname(){
       $("#"+content.image).remove();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Marc

Comment: You may want to use `eval(string)` to evaluate generated string of code.

Comment: What are you trying to do with these functions? There might be a better option than using eval().

Comment: The syntax you posted is obviously invalid; depending on what you want to do with it there is likely a way.

Comment: hey guys, thanks for all your answers.
I want to load functions dynamically with a JSON that has all information: lets say:
var content={[{"functionName": "first", "number":"2"},{"functionName": "second", "number":"3"}]};

Now I want to create a function "first" and use the number 2 as a variable and I want to create the function "second" with the variable 3 (just an example).

Comment: By "create a function" do you actually mean to **call** a function with that name? Because in order to create functions, they also need a body. Or do you want the functions to be empty? What's the point then?

Comment: I edited my question a little bit to hopefully explain it a little bit better.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function factory:

```
function factory(name, fn) {
    window[name] = fn
}

for(var i=1;i<=2;i++)
    factory('f'+i, function() { /*...*/ })
```

Answer (score 0):

in javascript a function can be also declared like this:

```
var func = function() { alert('hello'); }

func(); // call the function
```

so you can make an array of functions.. something like this:

```
var arr = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++) // there is no 'int' in javascript - the language is NOT strongly-typed
{
    var x = 'hello ' + (i + 1);

    arr.push(function()
    {
        alert(x);
    });
}

arr[0](); // call the first function
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in a slightly easier way:

```
var functions = {}; // this object will store all the generated functions

for(var i=1;i<=2;i++)
    functions['f' + i] = function(){}
```

Then you access a generated functions like `functions.f1()` for example

Basically it's just like what [David](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27137945/104380) has said, only he uses the global `window` object and I am using my own created one, not to pollute the global one and possibly be exposed to conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

It's super simple, in fact. The real question is: why? There should be no reason for you to do this, because if the function is the same (which it will be in your case), then you just need one function. Just pass it the "context" as an extra argument. Or, define an object prototype and use actual objects.

That said, let's dynamically make some functions! This is going to be flagged as "wtf are you doing, this is extremely bad practice" in the real world, btw. Not just by people, but also by javascript code validators like jslint and jshint.

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
  this["f"+i] = function() {
    console.log("lols!");
  };
}

f4(); // says "lols!"
```

If you want that `i` worked in, then you hit the "what are you doing, this is all wrong", because you might be tempted to do this:

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
  this["f"+i] = function() {
    console.log("lol "+i+"!");
  };
}

f4(); // says "lol 10!" ... wait what?
```

This'll say "lol 10", because the variable `i` is going to be 10 after all functions have been bound, and then when you call `f4()`, the var is checked, 10 is found, and it says "10". Not so handy.

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
  this["f"+i] = (function(v) {
    return function() {
      console.log("lol "+v+"!");
    };
  }(i));
}

f4(); // says "lol 4!", sweet!
```

Now it'll say the right thing, but we've properly hit the "holy crap what are you doing" level of bad coding. This makes absolutely no sense, and the real question is what we need these functions for. There isn't really any situation in which this approach is going to be better than the "real" way to solve the problem. For instance, you need to generate function output where a specific number matters? Okay, let's do that:

```
function pipenum(i) {
  console.log("lol "+i+"!");
}

pipenum(4); // says "lol 4!". Obviously.
```

If you, as human writing the source code, can write "f4()", then you can write "pipenum(4)", too. You basically just moved the (, this isn't even effort. And it's just as easy to work with as dynamic code:

```
var arg = 4; // obtained from user, or file, or whatever
this["f" + arg](...);
```

is weird and requires a bizarre function setup, whereas:

```
var arg = 4; // still obtained from user, or file, or whatever
this.pipenum(arg);
```

is plain old regular JS. No one's going to bat an eye at it, and jslint/jshint will not see anything out of the ordinary with it.

Comment: Currying is a good example of dynamic functions in JavaScript (not saying that the OP was looking for curry, just that dynamic functional programming as a concept isn’t just a WTF)

Comment: if you already know what you're doing almost nothing in JS is (it's a great language for that). This answer was mostly tailored to the level of programming the question represented =)

Comment: hey guys, thanks for all your answers.
I want to load functions dynamically with a JSON that has all information: lets say:
var content={[{"functionName": "first", "number":"2"},{"functionName": "second", "number":"3"}]};

Now I want to create a function "first" and use the number 2 as a variable and I want to create the function "second" with the variable 3 (just an example).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - JSON serialization does not include functions (the spec doesn't allow them) so what are you really doing, in which the JSON is simply one of the many possible ways in which you could have gotten the information you need to do what you want to do?

Comment: Yes the JSON should only provide the info to create a function (function-name and other infos like image-name, etc). so I want to create a function first(){/* Use image-name of first JSON node*/} and another one called second(){/* Use image-name of second JSON node*/}